# Excel formulas referencing multiple cells and sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook that currently has a few different sheets in it. There is one variable sheet which I have created LookUp Tables in for ease of reference in the other formulas. But I am now struggling on several formulas and I will ask questions individually now.

What I have and want to do is the following. I want to calculate the lot size based on Asset. Currently my Lot Size formula is this and it works based on the basic parameters I have.

```
=IFERROR(IF(ROUNDDOWN(AI7/O7,1)/10>$R$5,$R$5,ROUNDDOWN(AI7/O7,1)/10),0)
```

But what I want to do now is take this a step further. R5 is currently set to 100 which is the max lot size for 75% of the assets. But for the remaining 25% the max lot size is either 50 or 250 so I want the formula to now calculate this. If C5 = GBPUSD then Max lot size is 100 and max position is 50 giving me an overall result of 5000, if C5 is XAUUSD then max lot size is 50 and max position is 50 with an overall result of 2500. Now I have the Max lot size in my LookUp Table in Column 4 (D).

I have added a screenshot of the main spreadsheet and the variable sheet for reference.

[Variable Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziwQ9.png)

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs5Cj.png)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and tell us in which sheet you want to calculate the values Variable or Sample & GBPUSD and other reading from which sheet,,, !

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet in Dropbox hopefully that helps a little

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet in Dropbox hopefully that helps a little. I have highlighted the sheets I am currently working with RED [link] (https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/20jwh91m08smdg6c3y6sr/Back-Testing-2.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=pnjseowt8vun8zyx9jrs7trir)

Comment: Okay let me check .

Comment: Could u plz tell me in which cell of Sample sheet you need the formula or Z7 downwards need to be modified !!

Comment: So if we use the sample sheet in the workbook this is what I am trying to achieve. Column Z is where I want the formula. To explain the logic behind it this. If I use the example of GBPUSD I can place 1 trade with a maximum lot size of 100 and I can have a maximum of 50 open positions. Therefore the result in Column Z is 5000. If I trade XAUUSD then the max lot size is 50 and open positions is 50 the max result in Column Z would be 2500. So the formula I currently have works if I don't have different assets and I haven't used max open positions either. Hope that helps